# Duality of events between waiting times and stochastic process.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times

I was brushing up some notes on stochastic processes, and I noticed that in many examples, we have that given a stochastic process $N_t$, we have that the event
$$\{ N_t < k \} = \{ S_k > t\}$$
with $S_k$ being the time of the first arrival to the value $k$ given the process $N_t$. This construction basically denotes a *dual* stochastic process, I was wondering whether there was a name for such process. Furthermore, there's some deeper reason for this duality?

I put here some more examples since I'm no great writer:

- Consider a Poisson process $N_t$, i.e. increments are independents, identically distributed, and have distribution a Poisson distribution. Then if we define with $S_k = \inf \{t > 0 \mid N_t > k\}$ we have
  $$\{N_t < k\} = \{S_k > t\}$$
- Consider a one-dimensional Brownian motion $B_t$, then if we define $S_k = \inf \{t > 0 \mid\ B_t > k\}$ then
  $$\{B_t < k\} = \{S_k > t\}$$

Comment: Connected: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2205444

Comment: ...or my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1715476).

Comment: In fact, I just found something with a notion of _statistical duality_ described in this article: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0411462.pdf discussing in particular another "duality" between beta distributions and binomial distribution.

Comment: Any comment ?...